# https://localhost:8080/console : Hasura console not working for chrome browser

Tags: docker, google-chrome, docker-compose, hasura

I followed all the instructions mentioned at : https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/getting-started/docker-simple.html#docker-simple to run a local development setup that sets up both the Hasura GraphQL engine and Postgres using Docker Compose.

Here goes the images list that are available on my machine :

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
f0dfaed5fd49        hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.2   "graphql-engine serve"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes              0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   hasurademo_graphql-engine_1
8ea53eab404b        postgres:12                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes              5432/tcp                 hasurademo_postgres_1
ee167465a816        145bba7bd355                   "/bin/sh -c 'dotnet …"   11 months ago       Exited (1) 9 months ago                             beautiful_elion
4b33ec70bc81        922385868cee                   "/bin/sh -c 'dotnet …"   12 months ago       Exited (1) 12 months ago                            cranky_jepsen
```

Now on opening the url : http://localhost:8080/console to open the Hasura console, I see an error only with Chrome browser but not with Firefox browser as shown in the image below :

[image]

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to access the console using `https`. If you look at the request url it says `Request URL: https://localhost:8000/console`.

Chrome does this sometimes, so you have to make sure you type out the `http://`

Comment: Thanks @Nohac for your response.  I see the same response in case of url : http://localhost:8080/console too

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro If that doesn't work, you can try to access it through incognito.
You can also look at this stackoverflow question: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the console server flag for it to be available

`HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: true`

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo Alves for your response. The flag is already set to true as mentioned  below :                                                                                                                                  ## enable the console served by server
HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console

Answer (score 0):

In development I would suggest to not use the built-in console from the server itself, instead you can launch the console from CLI and point to your server.

you only need a config.yaml file with the following content:

config.yaml

```
version: 2
endpoint: http://localhost:8080
admin_secret: secret
```

then launch the console with the CLI:

```
hasura console
```

This way you will get the console running, and when you make changes they will go into you metadata folder, so you add them to git.